# FacebookSDK Request.newMeRequest onCompleted called on JELLYBEAN but not KITKAT or LOLLIPOP

Tags: android, facebook, request, facebook-android-sdk

This code results in the onCompleted method being called on Samsung JELLYBEAN but not on Motorola KITKAT or LG LOLLIPOP devices. The log returns: `W/Facebook test(20699): Facebook session status changed - OPENED - Exception: null` on all devices.

```
private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        String message = "Facebook session status changed - "
                + session.getState() + " - Exception: " + exception;                     
        Log.w("Facebook test", message);
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    Log.d("onCompleted",""); 
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        } 
    }
}
```

I have checked permissions and the hashes stored. This is my onActivityResult method:

```
  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
```

**UPDATE:** I created a test project with identical code to the problem app. This project doesn't have the problem, which suggests it isn't a java issue. The manifests are the same with regards to Facebook. I have the correct app_id in each case. The settings of the apps on developers.facebook.com are the same except for package name, class name and key hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Go to developers.facebook.com
- Select your app
- Select Status and Review
- Change "Do you want to make this app and all its live features
  available to the general public?" to NO
  *(I waited about ten minutes at this point, which may not be necessary)*
- Then change the same setting back to YES